# Reckoned version 0.1.0-beta.1 is (and cannot be) less than base version 1.4.0-beta.x

Tags: git, devops, pipeline

I am new to devops, so sorry if my question sounds stupid. We are using gitlab for our pipeline purpose and using rackon for creating tag.
On our dev branch , rackon was creating tags with 1.4.0-beta.x and was working fine, after last commit now the build starts failing with error message:

```
Reckoned version 0.1.0-beta.1 is (and cannot be) less than base version 1.4.0-beta.23
```

Last successful tag was 1.4.0-beta.23 , For build stage we are using gradle with rackon to create tag and then pushing that tag with normal git push command.

```
  - ./gradlew clean -Preckon.stage=$stage -Preckon.scope=$scope
  - ./gradlew docker -x test reckonTagCreate -Preckon.stage=$stage -Preckon.scope=$scope
  - git push --tag
```

Any suggestions what is wrong after last commit done on dev branch after user2dev merge. Any help appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so basically found issue was happening due to not a proper down merge and upmerge was done and somehow reckon gone heywire, after doing proper downmerge and upmerge things are back and reckon is creating right tag.